Creating order in a Postman using BigCommerce API
I'm trying to create an order in a Postman using BigCommerce API. I have already created a cart and checkout ID. While creating an order and putting in all the necessary details, I'm getting a 422 error status.
This is how I entered the Billing details:
{
  "billing_address": {
    "first_name": "Pushkar",
    "last_name": "Dutta",
    "street_1": "527 Abraham Tunnel",
    "city": "Austin",
    "state": "Texas",
    "zip": "78751",
    "country": "United States",
    "country_iso2": "US",
    "email": "pushkar.d@ignitiv.com"
  },
  "products": [
    {
      "name": "[Sample] Able Brewing System",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price_inc_tax": 10.25,
      "price_ex_tax": 10.25
    }
  ]
}

Error:
{
    "status": 422,
    "title": "The billing details for this order are incomplete.",
    "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/api-status-codes"
}


How are you creating this order?
You mentioned creating the cart and checkout, which suggests you would use the convert checkout to order call https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-management/checkouts/checkout-orders#create-an-order In which case I don't know what this body is - you wouldn't pass the address in the the body of this call, you would collect consignments on your checkout then convert your checkout to an order.

The reason why I don't think you're using the main create an order call https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-management/orders#create-an-order is because I just tried it, and this exact body works fine for me.
